# Artifactory Build Info Recorder: deploy artifacts set to false, artifacts will not be deployed

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, artifactory

I'm working on a CI pipeline and when I execute the script(Jenkins file), build is getting through and it says build is successful but binaries are not uploaded to Artifactory and I see this message on the log

"Artifactory Build Info Recorder: deploy artifacts set to false, artifacts will not be deployed"

Please help

Answer (score 1):

You are probably running a maven build with the following configuration:

```
rtMaven.deployer.deployArtifacts = false
```

This configuration disables artifacts deployment to Artifactory. If you want the artifacts to be deployed during the build, change this configuration to `true` or simply delete it. 
You can also deploy the artifacts in a later stage, if you collected build info, by calling:

```
rtMaven.deployer.deployArtifacts buildInfo
```

Check [this pipeline](https://github.com/jfrog/project-examples/blob/master/jenkins-examples/pipeline-examples/scripted-examples/maven-deploy-example/Jenkinsfile) for an example of late deploy, or [this pipeline](https://github.com/jfrog/project-examples/blob/master/jenkins-examples/pipeline-examples/scripted-examples/maven-example/Jenkinsfile) for an example of regular deploy. More details can be found in the [documentation](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Scripted+Pipeline+Syntax#ScriptedPipelineSyntax-MavenBuildswithArtifactory).

If this doesn't answer your question please share your pipeline with us.

Comment: Thanks, this worked for me. Appreciate your time and effort.

Comment: @Murthuja With pleasure. Please upvote and accept the answer to make it easier for others to find